# Using regex.extract with capture-groups argument fails when capture-group is null

Tags: mac, numbers

Using regex.extract in MacOS 11.0 Big Sur numbers app version 10.3.5 (7029.5.5) on MacBook Air M1.

Using a regular expression which contains one or more capture-groups that are not filled by a match, bizarre things like null results occur. It doesn't always happen or different things happen but typing in the following into a previously empty cell produces a null cell instead of "|D|E||" consistently in my environment:

```
        =CONCATENATE("|",REGEX.EXTRACT("DEX","(D)(E?)|(F?)",1,1),"|"
                ,REGEX.EXTRACT("DEX","(D)(E?)|(F?)",1,2),"|"
                ,REGEX.EXTRACT("DEX","(D)(E?)|(F?)",1,3),"|")
```

Change the 1,3 on the third line to 1,2 and you get "|D|E|E|" as expected. Change 1,2 back to 1,3 and you still get "|D|E|E|" (?!?). This bug has been there since the first release of Numbers 10 a few months ago on Intel silicon.

To me it looks like a null C-string missing its terminator byte.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? If you are looking for help in getting the formula right we might need to see a sample of the input data and the expected result.

Comment: I don't have a question per se. I think there is a bug in the handling of null capture-groups that prevents extraction of that null capture-group. Perhaps someone can see what is going on and provide a workaround. The formula is merely a sample formula that illustrates the problem and the input data is supplied in the formula itself as "DEX". The problem for this specific formula is that it doesn't show "|D|E||" in the cell as it should if the third capture-group is null but instead shows "" (null) and the retrieved values of all three capture-groups referenced in the formula are lost.

Comment: Perhaps this is a better example:
        IF(REGEX.EXTRACT("DEX","(D)(E?)|(F?)",1,3)="F",TRUE,FALSE)
The formula produces null rather than true or false.